# flask sqlalchemy - dynamically generate data model based on columns in the database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Is there a way to generate db model dynamically based on the columns in the database table for Flask SQLAlchemy?

I have an application to display data in from a database table, but the column name would change at times and break my app. I would like to have a way to generate the data model dynamically based on the actual column names in the database.

I currently explicitly declare all the columns as below.

```
class MyDbModel(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    id = db.Column('id', db.NVARCHAR(length=300), primary_key=True)
    name= db.Column('name', db.NVARCHAR(length=300),
                          nullable=True)
```

I'm not very familiar with sqlalchamy, I have tried the following but is getting an error as below, and I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.

`could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table`

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper

    db = SQLAlchemy()

    class MyDbModel(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'my_table'

        def __init__(self):
            #helper function to get column headers of a db table
            table_cols = get_headers_or_columns(
                'my_table'
            )
            t = Table(
                'my_table', db.metadata,
                Column('id', db.NVARCHAR(length=300), primary_key=True),
                *(Column(table_col, db.NVARCHAR(length=300)) for table_col in table_cols)
            )

            mapper(self, t)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, in case anyone needed. It's really simple, use a helper function to get the column headers of your table, then just use `setattr` to set the attributes of the class.

```
from app import db

class MyDbModel(db.Model):
        pass

def map_model_attrs(model, table):
    """
    :param model: your db Model Class
    :param table your db table name
    """

    table_cols = get_headers_or_columns(table)

    for col in table_cols:
        setattr(
            model, col, db.Column(col, db.NVARCHAR(length=300),
                                  nullable=True)
        )

map_mode_attrs(MyDbModel, 'my_table')
```